# Replace eval() method

Tags: javascript, eval

```
var params = "["test@google.com", "param1", "param2", "param3", ""]";
var result = eval(params)
```

And the result of eval(params) is :

```
["test@google.com", "param1", "param2", "param3", ""]
```

How can i replace eval(params) and getting the same result ?

```
["test@google.com", "param1", "param2", "param3", ""]
```

Comment: your first line is broken and your question is unclear...

Comment: I think you are looking for `JSON.parse`, but your example is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var params = "[\"test@google.com\", \"param1\", \"param2\", \"param3\", \"\"]"
JSON.parse(params)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var params = JSON.parse('["test@google.com", "param1", "param2", "param3", ""]');
console.log(params);
```

OR

```
var params = '["test@google.com", "param1", "param2", "param3", ""]';
eval(params);
```

And your output is :

```
["test@google.com", "param1", "param2", "param3", ""]
```